# Adobe build doesn't accept any plugins in my config.xml file (malformed config.xml)

Tags: xml, cordova, config, phonegap-build

I am building an application that uses Cordova 3.0.0, it is pretty simple but I require adding some plugins in the config.xml file, but whenever I add any plugin lines in the config.xml file, Phonegap Build tells me that the XML is malformed, here is the XML I am using:

AppName
    
        My app description
    
    
        Example Creator

```
<icon src="img/icon.png" />

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.geolocation" />
```

Whenever I remove the line:  everything works, but if that line is there (or a similar line for any plugin whatsoever), I receive the error message (**malformed config.xml**).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was having a similiar issue, and finally found out that the `malformed config.xml` is being caused by the `gap:plugin`.

In my case it was the xml namespace that was defined incorretly. Look at the top of your file, it should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.phonegap.example"
    version     = "0.0.1" >
```

Where the important part is having `xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"`, which in my case was only `xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up Cordova calls and Phonegap Build calls. For geolocation, in your Phonegap Build config.xml you need the following:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
```

Do NOT put this:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.geolocation" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Cordova will actually take care of all the plugin stuff for you as of 3.0.0. Just run `cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git` from the command line in your project directory.

Also see the docs on Geolocation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation).